# Who was in charge of Deep Space Nine during the "The Search"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the third season of DS9, the entire station's compliment of commanding officers leave for the Gamma Quadrant. I do not believe this is an isolated incident, there seem to be several times throughout the series when the command officers are all absent from the station.

So who is in charge back on Deep Space Nine when this happens?

Comment: Perhaps the attention-seeking "puppy" program was let out of its doghouse?  (from 1x17, [The Forsaken](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Forsaken_(episode)))

Comment: Whomever is next in the *chain of command*?

Comment: @CamelBlues which is who? DS9 has significantly fewer officers and personnel in general. It seems like all of the officers went to the Gamma Quadrant.

Comment: There was no one else. In the event that Quark wasn't with them, then he was left in charge. If Quark was with them, then Rom was left in charge.

Comment: I'd take Bajoran Security officer #3 over Rom any day of the Bajoran week.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I always thought Michael Eddington was left in charge.

I don't remember seeing him on the Defiant, and he was head of security...

Comment: That makes sense; he was introduced in the previous episode, perhaps to close this very plot hole.

Answer (score 8):

My guess would be that the night shift command officer was left in charge, or perhaps a Bajoran officer other than Kira.  There is very little attention paid to the other shifts in most Star Trek series.  Sometimes some of the books give them some attention.  For instance we learn that Chekov was the night watch officer on Enterprise during the first season of TOS.  But those aren't generally given the blessing of canon in the Star Trek universe.

The point is that there are likely numerous officers, both Starfleet and Bajoran on Deep Space Nine that we never hear anything about, any one of which could be left in charge in case the primary crew is absent, asleep or incapacitated.

Answer (score -2):

If ODO remained on DS9 then I think he would be in charge.he held the rank of CONSTABLE and I beieved he was head of security.

Comment: Constable isn't a rank, it's a civilian position. And on a joint Starfleet/Bajoran military installation, his rank wouldn't count for anything in the chain of command.

Comment: @Valorum: We don't know a whole lot about the ranks of many of the Bajoran crewmembers on DS9, do we? Odo seems to be above all the security staff on DS9, and he is wearing a Bajoran military uniform (even though it's not a "real" one made out of cloth). [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Odo) says "Odo never held any rank apart from the title constable", but doesn't provide a source (thus making it possible the rank he formally holds is simply not used in conversation with him), but also that "Odo once mentioned that he was a commissioned officer in the Bajoran militia"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I'm struggling to recall when he said that last bit. A quick check of Chakoteya reveals that Odo never said the words "commission", "commissioned" or "Militia" and that he only said the word "officer" in relation to him being an officer of the courts on Cardassia

Comment: @Valorum: That's right, MA claims that's from "The Search, Part 1", but I can't find any such statement in the episode's transcript.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - He's the "*official Bajoran representative"*. http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/447.htm